# Разделение файла java

Tags: java

Задача:

Нужно разделить файл на 2 файла по ровну если в главном файле нечетное кол-во байт то в 1 файл записать на 1 больше байт.

Никак не могу понять как сделать разделение чтобы оно записалось

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("e:/name.txt");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("e:/name1.txt");
        FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream("e:/name2.txt");
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (in.available()>0){
            list.add(in.read());
        }
        int count = 0;
        if (list.size()%2==0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size()/2; i++) {
                int data = in.read();
            out.write(data);
            count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что не так с этим кодом?

Answer (score 3):

```
File file = new File("e:/name.txt");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
long length = file.length();
long part1Length = length / 2 + length % 2;
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("e:/name1.txt");
FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream("e:/name2.txt");
long read = 0;
int b;
while ((b = in.read()) >= 0){
    if(++read <= part1Length)
        out.write(b);
    else
        out2.write(b);
}
out.close();
out2.close();
```

P.S. метод `available` не предназначен для определения конца файла, почитайте javadoc к нему.